# Can this equation proved without writing down the elements of matrix and vectors

Tags: derivatives, vectors

I found a nice [appendix](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/0471705195.app3/pdf) on the differentiation with respect to a vector in the book Applied Numerical Methods Using Matlab by Won Young Yang, Wenwu Cao, Tae-Sang Chung, and John Morris.

There they have this equality (C.6):

$$\cfrac \partial {\partial x} x^TAx=(A+A^T)x,$$ where $x$ is a column vector and $A$ is a square matrix with appropriate dimensions.

If I use another equation from the document: $$x^TAy=\sum_{m=1}^M \sum_{n=1}^N a_{mn} x_m y_n$$ (where $y$ is a column vector and $M$ and $N$ are dimensions of matrix $A$) I could verify this. But I wonder, is there a way to obtain (C.6) using another approach. E.g. using the previous properties they list in that document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to follow these types of calculations if we use the definition that the gradient vector is the unique vector $v$ so that
$$ \lim_{\lvert h \rvert \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-v \cdot h}{\lvert h \rvert} = 0 $$
(note this will revert to something equivalent to the definition of the ordinary derivative if the variables are scalars). Then
$$ f(x+h)-f(x) = (x+h)^T A (x+h)-x^TAx = h^T Ax + x^T Ah + h^T Ah = (Ax + A^T x) \cdot h + h^T Ah. $$
The latter term tends to zero faster than $\lvert h \rvert$ does, and so the gradient vector is the vector in the linear term, $Ax + A^T x$, as expected.

Comment: Thanks. What subject should I study to be able to do this kind of manipulation? Like vector calculus? Matrix calculus? Can you mention a good book?

Comment: Any decent first book in multivariable calculus should cover this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can! But you'll need some preliminaries (edit: if you follow Chaper's answer, which is simpler and more intrinsic, you don't even need these preliminaries):

1). For each real symmetric matrix $S$ there exists some square matrix $Q$ such that $S=Q^TQ$.

2). Chain rule for multivariate differentiation.

Assuming you are fammiliar with both 1) and 2), let's start:

Let $Q:=A+A^T$, and assume $Q=S^TS$, then $x^TQx = (Sx)^T(Sx)$. Let $y:=Sx$, then
$$D_x(x^TQx)=D_y (y^Ty)D_x(Sx)=2y^TS=2x^TS^TS=2x^TQ$$
Or
$$D_x (x^TAx) + D_x(x^TA^Tx) = 2x^T(A+A^T).$$
Since $x^TAx$ is a *number*, we know $x^TAx=x^TA^Tx$. Now the equation in question follows.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for the version of chain rule you mentioned?

Comment: @anapprentice for multivariate mappings $f:\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^n$ and $g:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^k$, we have that $$D(g\circ f)|_x=(Dg)|_{f(x)}(Df)|_x.$$ where $D$ denotes the Jacobian matrix.

Comment: Thanks. What subject should I study to be able to do this kind of manipulation? Like vector calculus? Matrix calculus? Can you mention a good book?

Comment: @anapprentice any sensible textbook on multivariate calculus.